# How can I sort in Solr empty fields to the last position?

Tags: solr

I have in Apache Solr a field named "firstname" with a String in it, which can be empty. I want to sort the field in ascending order, but if it is empty, how can I determine that it should be sorted to the end?

I already tried sortMissingLast="true", but it didn't go as expected, because it only sorts fields last, if the field is missing and not an empty value.

Comment: If you control the indexing of the data you could get this to work by not saving the `firstname` field when the value is empty (or by saving it as a null instead of an empty string when the value is empty)

Comment: Depending on the size of your index (a small index with not too many queries might be usable - this is a hack), the worse option might be to sort by a combination of functions, something like `sort=if(termfreq(firstname,''),999999999,ord(firstname))` - i.e. if the term is an empty string, use a very large value, otherwise use the actual sorted index position of the value. You couldn't use string comparisons directly in `if` previously, but that might work now; another option is to use `sub` or a similar function to find the difference between `''` and the actual term in the sorted order

Comment: Putting strings that are white-space only into Solr is an anti-pattern. The best way to solve this problem is by not creating it in the first place. If there's no text for a field, don't send a value. In the case of JSON updates, omitting the field entirely or giving it a value of "" or null will result in no value, but " " gives you a field that has a space as a value (at least for the Solr 9.1 I had handy to test it).